# How to improve the efficiency of a function

Tags: r, function, performance, dataset, categorical-data

I wrote this function to transform a dataset with **categorical** variables with only the observed combinations of categories into a dataset that contains all the possible combinations that can be found with the variables and categories considered. Moreover I want to have a column "y" that contains the frequency of the row, so how many times I have observed in my original dataset that pattern.

```
datafreq <- function(dati) {
  dati = na.omit(dati)
  dati[] = lapply(dati, factor)
  dati <-  dati %>%
    group_by_all(.drop = FALSE) %>%
    summarise(y = n()) %>%
    ungroup()
  return(as.data.frame(dati))
}
```

So for example you have the dataset **votes** that can be found in UCI Machine Learning repository https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/congressional+voting+records.

It has 435 rows, each with a combination of values of the 16 categorical variables.

I would like to obtain a dataset with 3^16 rows, one for each combination (observed and not observed) of the categories of the variables (each variable has 3 possible categories). It should be created a variable y that counts the number of times each combination has been observed in the data (0 if never been observed).

The function that I wrote works well and do what it should with very **small dataset**. However, when used with large dataset like votes, R crashes.
So I am asking whether there exists a more efficient function that I can use, how can I improve in efficiency?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post examples of `dati` and `factor`? It is a bit unclear what format these should take. Also, an example of the expected output would be helpful.

Comment: Done! I have wrote better what I need. An example of dati is the dataset votes. factor is the r function that transforms in factor the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread("C:/temp/house-votes-84.data", header = FALSE)
u <- lapply(dt, unique)
a <- rev(cumprod(c(1, rev(lengths(u)[-1]))))
dt2 <- do.call(CJ, lapply(lengths(u), seq.int))
dt2[,counts := tabulate(colSums(t(mapply(function(i) match(dt[[i]], u[[i]]), seq_along(dt)) - 1)*a) + 1, .N)]
nrow(dt) == sum(dt2$counts)
#> [1] TRUE
```

The values in `dt2` are the indices of the values in `u`, so `dt2[i, j]` corresponds to `u[[j]][dt2[i, j]]`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Updating my answer to present a simpler and efficient solution.

```r
library(data.table)
library(collapse)

dt <- fread("~/house-votes-84.data", header = FALSE)
dt[, ("V1") := NULL]
dt2 <- crossed_join(dt, strings_as_factors = TRUE)

# Add counts
dt[, ("n") := .N, by = names(dt)]
# Left Join
dt2[dt, ("n") := get("n"), on = names(dt2)]
# Fill NA with zero
setnafill(dt2, cols = "n", fill = 0L, type = "const")
dt2
#>           V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 n
#>        1:  n  y  n  y  y  y  n  n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   n   y 1
#>        2:  n  y  n  y  y  y  n  n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   n   ? 0
#>        3:  n  y  n  y  y  y  n  n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   n   n 0
#>        4:  n  y  n  y  y  y  n  n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   y   y 0
#>        5:  n  y  n  y  y  y  n  n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   y   ? 0
#>       ---                                                          
#> 43046717:  y  ?  ?  n  n  ?  ?  ?   ?   ?   y   ?   n   ?   y   ? 0
#> 43046718:  y  ?  ?  n  n  ?  ?  ?   ?   ?   y   ?   n   ?   y   n 0
#> 43046719:  y  ?  ?  n  n  ?  ?  ?   ?   ?   y   ?   n   ?   ?   y 0
#> 43046720:  y  ?  ?  n  n  ?  ?  ?   ?   ?   y   ?   n   ?   ?   ? 0
#> 43046721:  y  ?  ?  n  n  ?  ?  ?   ?   ?   y   ?   n   ?   ?   n 0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

## crossed_join function

```
Ccj <- getFromNamespace("Ccj", "data.table")
# Function to perform the cross-join
crossed_join <- function(X, sort = FALSE, unique = TRUE,
                         as_dt = TRUE,
                         strings_as_factors = FALSE, 
                         log_limit = 8){
  x_nms <- names(X)
  if (unique){
    X <- lapply(X, function(x) collapse::funique(x, sort = sort))
  } else if (sort){
    X <- lapply(X, radix_sort)
  } else {
    X <- as.list(X)
  }
  expanded_n <- prod(collapse::vlengths(X, use.names = FALSE))
  if (log10(expanded_n) >= log_limit || expanded_n > .Machine$integer.max){
    stop("Requested expansion results in >= ",
         expanded_n,
         " rows, aborting.")
  }
  if (strings_as_factors){
    is_chr <- vapply(X, FUN = is.character,
                     FUN.VALUE = logical(1),
                     USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    if (any(is_chr)){
      which_chr <- which(is_chr)
      X[which_chr] <- lapply(X[which_chr],
                             function(x) collapse::qF(x,
                                                      sort = FALSE,
                                                      ordered = FALSE,
                                                      na.exclude = FALSE))
    }
  }
  out <- .Call(Ccj, X)
  if (!is.null(x_nms)){
    out <- stats::setNames(out, x_nms)
  }
  if (as_dt){
    data.table::setDT(out)
    data.table::setalloccol(out)
  }
  out
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is not completely what I was searching for. I have edited the question with input and output example of what I am needing. Please look at it and correct your answer.